# Processing text from SQLite3 Database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 database containing sentences of Japanese text and additional characters called furigana which help with the phonetic reading.

I have a function, remove_furigana, which can process a string and return the string without the furigana characters. However, when I pass this function the sentences pulled from my database it doesn't seem to have any effect. Could someone clarify for me what is going on here and point me in the direction of a solution?

```
def remove_furigana(content):
    furigana = False
    expression = ""
    for character in content:
        if character == '[':
            furigana = True
        elif character == ']':
            furigana = False
        elif not furigana:
            expression += character
    return expression.replace(" ", "")

def retrieve_article():
    c.execute('SELECT content FROM sentence WHERE article_id = "k10010770581000"')
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(remove_furigana(row))
```

Comment: You are passing it a row, not a word. `row` is actually a _tuple_. Try printing it `print(row)` to see what is being sent to your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python SQLite [fetchall function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) returns a tuple consisted of the fields in that record. You need to send the `content` column to the function:

```
def retrieve_article():
    c.execute('SELECT content FROM sentence WHERE article_id = "k10010770581000"')
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(remove_furigana(row[0]))
```

Alternatively, you can use [row_factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) to get dictionaries rather than tuples:

```
import sqlite3

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:") con.row_factory = dict_factory
```

In that case, the fetchall result will be dictionary and you can access the `content` field as:

```
    print(remove_furigana(row['content']))
```